# What's the local law of propagation of disturbances

Tags: mathematical-physics, waves, geometric-optics

In Vladimir I. Arnold's *Lectures on Partial Differential Equations*, Chapter 3 *Huygens' Principle in the Theory of Wave Propagation*, which is devoted to the proof of Huygens principle (original one by Huygens, maybe not by Fresnel), it's said that

> the contact elements of space-time that are tangent to the large front belong to the retardation hypersurface.

By *contact elements of space-time tangent to the large front*, he means roughly the tangent hyperplanes of the large front, if the space-time is just simply $\mathbb R^3\times\mathbb R$ (It's generally a manifold $M^{n+1}=B^n\times\mathbb R$, where $B^n$ is the manifold of physical space). By *the large front*, he means the geometric object in the space-time that describes the poropagation of fronts of perturbations by means of a single hypersurface in space-time with a more general retardation hypersurface in the manifold of contact elements of space-time, or simply just the graph of all fronts in the space-time. By *retardation hypersurface*, maybe he means *Fresnel hypersurface*, i.e. a hyperplane in the manifold of co-oriented contact elements of space-time defined by the field of cones of possible velocities. He says that

> In geometric optics, *a cone of possible velocities of motion* is prescribed at each point of the space-time manifold $M$.

For example, in the flat space of vacuum, the light cone is prescribed at each point of the space time.

And the points of *Fresnel hypersurface* are just the tangent planes to the cones of possible velocities of motion in the manifold of contact elements, i.e, the bundle of $PT^*M\to M$ or co-oriented $ST^*M\to M$.

In order to understand these concepts, a solid physical maturity seems needed, which I haven't, so I want to fix the gaps in my knowledge of physics. First,

> What's the local law of propagation of disturbances in the geometric optics?

Second,

> What's the physical meaning of the *Fresnel hypersurface*? Is it well-known or related to other well-known terms?

I need some clues. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if it is the same concept as Fresnel surfaces, which indicates the possible values of the wave vector $\vec k$ and the frequency $\omega$, for an electromagnetic field. These are called dispersion relations, and these constraints come from the applications of the Maxwell equations. In the vacuum, applying Maxwell equations, the relations are simply $\frac{\vec k^2}{\omega^2}=1$, so in the $\frac{\vec k}{\omega}$ space, it is just a sphere (the "light-cone").

Comment: ....But in a material continuum, the Maxwell equations are different, so the constraints (dispersion relations) are different, so the Fresnel surface is no more a sphere (see for instance the pages $1$ to $4$ of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0569.pdf) ) See also this pretty [image](http://imaginary.org/sites/default/files/styles/gallery-full/public/fresnel_wave_surface_xi.jpg?itok=5I9L5vEB)

Comment: @Trimok Maybe it's related but different. I did google and meet the same arXiv paper, but it seems that they're different things. Arnold's argument is based on the the concept of contact. A canonical problem is to find the Legendre manifold for a contact structure, namely a maximal manifold tangent to all contact elements. It's the geometric theory of PDE, which I started to learn.

Comment: @Trimok In addition, I need some general concepts on waves, no matter the underlying physical structure is electromagnetic wave or mechanical wave. It's not even described by harmonic functions if possible. Arnold's goal is to prove Huygens principle. Unfortunately, many of Arnold's terminologies are used only by himself alone!